# Change Data Source Properties in WebLogic with WLST

Tags: dynamic, weblogic, wlst

Is it possible to change the URL of a datasource for only one webapp while keeping the others with the old values in WebLogic? I was thinking of using the WebLogic Scripting tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because datasources exist indepently of the deployed applications.

Instead, define a second datasource with different URL, and direct your special application to use that instead of the original datasource.

Comment: exactly that it's what I'm trying to avoid... I was thinking in maybe take the exist DS and override it on fly with WLST , without affect the others apps...

Comment: @elopez I know, but exactly that is what is not possible imho. Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

```
connect('weblogic', 'zhaonz7758258..', 't3://%s:%s' % ('localhost','7001'))
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/')
cd('JDBCSystemResources/zhaonengzhi/JDBCResource/zhaonengzhi/JDBCDriverParams/zhaonengzhi/Properties/zhaonengzhi/Properties/user')
cmo.setValue('ESB')
cd('/')
cd('JDBCSystemResources/zhaonengzhi/JDBCResource/zhaonengzhi/JDBCDriverParams/zhaonengzhi')
cmo.setPassword('ESB')
cd('/')
save()
activate(block='true')
disconnect()
exit()
```

Comment: This is an English language site. All questions and answers must be written in English. Please edit your answer to comply with that requirement.